# Get only ethernet MAC-address via command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I use 'ipconfig /all' or 'getmac /v' to get all NIC physical addresses.

But the problem is, generally a computer has more than one NIC card. Also, there are some virtual MAC addresses like Microsoft virtual wifi hotspot NIC which shows only when wifi hotspot is on.

So, how can I collect only the address corresponding to ethernet via cmd?

Answer (score 6):

This command fetches MAC addresses of **physical** ethernet network devices:

```
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where "PNPDeviceID like '%PCI%' AND AdapterTypeID='0'" get name, MacAddress
```

if you want to fetch **virtual** ones as well then use this:

```
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where "AdapterTypeID='0'" get name, MacAddress
```

or this one for fetching all the MAC addresses of **all network devices**:

```
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter get name, MacAddress
```

Just in case you are interested how it works:
We are using [WMIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) tool provided by Windows to fetch adapter info from [Win32_NetworkAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216.aspx).
Then filter ethernet adapters by `AdapterTypeID=0` as `0` [corresponds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216.aspx) to ethernet type.
Finally filter physical devices with `PNPDeviceID like '%PCI%` since they are attached to PCI.

You might also want to look at the result of whole Win32_NetworkAdapter and play with it with this command:

```
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter
```

Comment: Thanks. The 1st command is working fine but the 2nd one is giving an error: invalid verb

Comment: Updated. I've just missed a doublequote. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 4):

I advise to you use powershell because very powerful than cmd

```
Get-CimInstance win32_networkadapterconfiguration | select description, macaddress | where {$_.MACAddress -ne $n
ull }
```

**output** :

```
description                                                 macaddress
-----------                                                 ----------
RAS Async Adapter                                           20:41:53:59:4E:FF
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller                          18:03:73:65:64:AB
VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1                  00:50:56:C0:00:01
VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8                  00:50:56:C0:00:08
```

that command in powershell select all macaddress for device enable your machine that included vmware but we can do more filter for example

```
Get-CimInstance win32_networkadapterconfiguration | select description, macaddress | where {$_.MACAddress -ne $n
ull }  | where {$_.Description -match "Realtek" }
```

**output**:

```
description                                                 macaddress
-----------                                                 ----------
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller                          18:03:73:65:64:AB
```

but if your just run in cmd you should encode this command in powershell like this

```
$script={ Get-CimInstance win32_networkadapterconfiguration | select description, macaddress | where {$_.MACAddr
ess -ne $null }  | where {$_.Description -match "Realtek" } }

[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes( $script))
```

output **encoded command for use in cmd**

```
IABHAGUAdAAtAEMAaQBtAEkAbgBzAHQAYQBuAGMAZQAgAHcAaQBuADMAMgBfAG4AZQB0AHcAbwByAGsAYQBkAGEAcAB0AGUAcgBjAG8AbgBmAGkAZwB1AHI
AYQB0AGkAbwBuACAAfAAgAHMAZQBsAGUAYwB0ACAAZABlAHMAYwByAGkAcAB0AGkAbwBuACwAIABtAGEAYwBhAGQAZAByAGUAcwBzACAAfAAgAHcAaABlAH
IAZQAgAHsAJABfAC4ATQBBAEMAQQBkAGQAcgBlAHMAcwAgAC0AbgBlACAAJABuAHUAbABsACAAfQAgACAAfAAgAHcAaABlAHIAZQAgAHsAJABfAC4ARABlA
HMAYwByAGkAcAB0AGkAbwBuACAALQBtAGEAdABjAGgAIAAiAFIAZQBhAGwAdABlAGsAIgAgAH0AIAA=
```

in cmd i use this and get mac

```
powershell -encodedcommand IABHAGUAdAAtAEMAaQBtAEkAbgBzAHQAYQBuA
GMAZQAgAHcAaQBuADMAMgBfAG4AZQB0AHcAbwByAGsAYQBkAGEAcAB0AGUAcgBjAG8AbgBmAGkAZwB1A
HIAYQB0AGkAbwBuACAAfAAgAHMAZQBsAGUAYwB0ACAAZABlAHMAYwByAGkAcAB0AGkAbwBuACwAIABtA
GEAYwBhAGQAZAByAGUAcwBzACAAfAAgAHcAaABlAHIAZQAgAHsAJABfAC4ATQBBAEMAQQBkAGQAcgBlA
HMAcwAgAC0AbgBlACAAJABuAHUAbABsACAAfQAgACAAfAAgAHcAaABlAHIAZQAgAHsAJABfAC4ARABlA
HMAYwByAGkAcAB0AGkAbwBuACAALQBtAGEAdABjAGgAIAAiAFIAZQBhAGwAdABlAGsAIgAgAH0AIAA=
```

**output:**

```
description                             macaddress
-----------                             ----------
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller      18:03:73:65:64:AB
```

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('getmac /v ^|find /i "local area conn" ') DO (
 FOR %%b IN (%%a) DO (
  SET element=%%b
  IF "!element:~2,1!!element:~5,1!!element:~8,1!"=="---" set mac=%%b
 )
)
ECHO found %mac%
GOTO :EOF
```

This should provide the information required, but it would have been better had you provided sample output from your machine as your experience may not be exactly reproduced on others' installations.

Comment: Hi, In my machine I had to use `getmac /v | find "Ethernet"` as the name was 'Ethernet' in my case. I am wondering if there is any method that will work for all user (independent of machine)

Answer (score 2):

on commandline:

```
for /f %i in ('wmic nic get  MACAddress ^|find ":"') do @echo %i
```

or

```
for /f %i in ('getmac^|find "-"') do @echo %i
```

for use in a batchfile, use `%%i` instead of `%i`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
netsh interface ip show addresses "Ethernet"
```

Comment: hey dude it's not work for all windows  my ethernet interface name is "local area connection" or some windows named "some things"!

Comment: Yeah change the name according to the name of your interface , for you it could be `netsh interface ip show addresses "Local Area Connection" `

Answer (score 1):

To *only* get the **active** network card's MAC-address using Powershell:

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME | Where{$_.IpEnabled -Match "True"} | Select-Object -Expand macaddress) -join ","
```