# batch file to read a specific string from txt

Tags: batch-file

I need some help to adjust a simple text.

I have generated a file from the command `getmac`.

The file looks like this:

```
1
2 F0-79-59-62-20-EB   \Device\Tcpip_{F4744941-2A87-4DFA-A61B-393B8830B0C3}  
3
```

My goal is to get to this point:

```
1 F0-79-59-62-20-EB
2    
3
```

I.e. delete every string after the MAC and move it to the first line
or just read the mac and insert it to a variable without editing it at all

Thanks
Best regards,
Mike

```
C:\Users\Test\Desktop>SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=*" %a IN (c:\mymac.txt) DO (
SET line=%a
IF "!line:~0,2!" == "2 " SET macline=%a
)

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>(
SET line=F0-79-59-62-20-EB   \Device\Tcpip_{F4744941-2A87-4DFA-A61B-                 
}
IF "!line:~0,2!" == "2 " SET macline=F0-79-59-62-20-EB        \Device\Tcpip_{F474494
1-2A87-4DFA-A61B-393B8830B0C3}
)

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %m IN ("") DO (
SET mac=%m
ECHO
)

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [get ONLY Ethernet MAC address via command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29201132/2152082)

Comment: `for /F "tokens=2" %a in ('findstr /L /B "2 " C:\mymac.txt) do set mac=%a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of your generated file seems to be totally different from the output of the `getmac` command - at least, it is on my machine.

You should be able to use (from the prompt - but most responses on SO are of a batch file)

```
FOR /F %a IN ('getmac') DO SET mac=%a

echo %mac%
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
it doesnt seem to work:/
which OS are you using? i use getmac /nh

Comment: I'm using Win7 and the solution I proposed also works for me using `getmac /nh`

Comment: OK so the problem is that my first attempt was a batch and even that i put pause at the end the window just closes very fast, i tried to do it manually in CMD and it worked

Comment: FOR /F %%a IN ('getmac') DO SET mac=%%a for batch
THanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question right, this should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (input.txt) DO (
    SET line=%%a
    IF "!line:~0,2!"=="2 " SET macline=%%a
)
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%m IN ("!macline!") DO (
    SET mac=%%m
)
```

At this point the mac ist stored in the `%mac%` variable. If you want to output it into your file, append this to the code:

```
ECHO 1 %mac% > output.txt
ECHO. >> output.txt
ECHO 2 >> output.txt
ECHO 3 >> output.txt
```

If you want to reuse the mac, it's stored in `%mac%`.

Comment: Please post your whole code and the content of the text file.

Comment: i am not able to insert pictures yet but nothing happens when i try to print it. eventually all i need is to extract the mac address from that file to an variable so i can use it for other batchs i made

Comment: i published my output in the question

Comment: the original txt looks different after running this batch
the whole text jumped to the first line

Comment: You've created the macline variable inside of a code block. You need to call it like `!macline!` instead of `%macline%`.